# Upgrading/Updating package using dpkg only

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg

I am building a script to automatically deploy a .net core worker service app as `systemd` `service unit`/`daemon`.

I wanted to double check: using solely `dpkg`, there is no other way to upgrade/update a package other than removing it first and then installing - is this correct ?

I read that `dpkg` -i will upgrade the package if it is already installed, but if the check is dependent on the `.deb` file name, than it does not help me, since the `.deb` file name contains the version in it and the version is incremented, meaning the new version `.deb` file name will never be the one currently installed.

So the way to go is removing and installing afterwards ?
This is the way I am currently doing it. Removing a package works by package name.
Wanted to double check if there is no shortcut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dpkg -i` will upgrade a package if it’s already installed, no need to remove it first. The package is checked using the metadata it contains (*e.g.* the package name as shown by `dpkg -l` after installation), not the file name.

Comment: wondered why it is not mentioned/indicated explicitly for the `-i` option through the `man dpkg`  - in Ubuntu.